# Is there a JavaScript user tracking framework / best practice site?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, user-tracking

I am upgrading the tracking of our company click monitoring tool.  Currently it uses a `<img/>` tag to call a page and pass the required information to our system.  We need to upgrade this to use `<script/>` tags and call a JavaScript file hosted on our server, Like Google Analytics Urchin Module

Is there a JavaScript framework / best practice written for this kind of tracking? If not I can write my own but wanted to check that there is not some tried and tested code / practice for doing this kind of tracking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for what it's worth, you don't want to track hits from people with JavaScript disabled?

Comment: we will use the img tag we have in a noscript tag as a fall back

Comment: Why not use Google Analytics? It allows for all kinds of custom event tracking in addition to just basic page views and such.

Comment: I would agree with Jimmy... why reinvent the wheel?  If you need more than Google Analytics, check out Urchin.  I think it is only around 3K which is probably cheaper than developing something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this open web analytics tool

http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/